# Accessing struct member by address

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Consider a struct with two members of integer type. I want to get both members by address. I can successfully get the first, but I'm getting wrong value with the second. I believe that is garbage value. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { int a; int b; } foo_t;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  foo_t f;
  f.a = 2;
  f.b = 4;
  int a = ((int)(*(int*) &f));
  int b = ((int)(*(((int*)(&f + sizeof(int)))))); 
  printf("%d ..%d\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm getting:

> 2 ..1

Can someone explain where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Why are you not doing it this way in your declaration for `int a` as in `int a = f.a;`? You're "accessing the structure" as if it was memory allocated, but clearly you are not!

Comment: @t0mm13b: purpose-learning..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The offset of the first member must always be zero by the C standard; that's why your first cast works. The offset of the second member, however, may not necessarily be equal to the size of the first member of the structure because of padding.

Moreover, adding a number to a pointer does not add the number of bytes to the address: instead, the size of the thing being pointed to is added. So when you add `sizeof(int)` to `&f`, `sizeof(int)*sizeof(foo_t)` gets added.

You can use [`offsetof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) operator if you want to do the math yourself, like this

```
int b = *((int*)(((char*)&f)+offsetof(foo_t, b)));
```

The reason this works is that `sizeof(char)` is *always* one, as required by the C standard.

Of course you can use `&f.b` to avoid doing the math manually.

Comment: Isn't `offsetof` a non-standard GCC extension?

Comment: @Dolda2000 No, that's ANSI C: see section 7.17.3 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf);

Comment: Are you sure? Even now when I look in the GCC manual, it lists `offsetof` under its C extensions. It might have been defined in the standard afterwards, of course.

Comment: @Dolda2000 According to the link in my prior comment, this has been a standard since at least 2005, but I think I used it cross-platform back in the late nineties. It could have started as a gcc extension, though.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `&f + sizeof(int)`. If `A` is a pointer, and `B` is an integer, then `A + B` does not, in C, mean `A` plus `B` bytes. Rather, it means `A` plus `B` elements, where the size of an element is defined by the pointer type of `A`. Therefore, if `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your architecture, then `&f + sizeof(int)` means "four `foo_t`s into `&f`, or 4 * 8 = 32 bytes into `&f`".

Try `((char *)&f) + sizeof(int)` instead.

Or, of course, `&f.a` and `&f.b` instead, quite simply. The latter will not only give you handy `int` pointers anyway and relieve you of all those casts, but also be well-defined and understandable. :)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `&f + sizeof(int)` adds a number to a pointer of type `foo_t*`.  Pointer arithmetic always assumes the pointer is to an element of an array, and the number is treated as a count of elements.

So if `sizeof(int)` is 4, `&f + sizeof(int)` points four `foo_t` structs past `f`, or `4*sizeof(foo_t)` bytes after `&f`.

If you must use byte counts, something like this might work:

```
int b = *(int*)((char*)(&f) + sizeof(int));
```

... assuming there's no padding between members `a` and `b`.

But is there any reason you don't just get the value `f.b` or the pointer `&f.b`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `&f.b`, and skip the actual pointer math.

Here is how I would change your `int b` line:

```
int b = (int)(*(((int*)(&(f.b)))));
```

BTW, when I run your program as is, I get `2 ..0` as the output.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
  int b = ((int)(*(int*)((int)&f + sizeof(int))));
```

You are interpreting &f as a pointer and when you are adding 4 (size of int) to it, it interprets it as adding 4 pointers which is 16 or 32 bytes depending on 32 vs 64 arch.  If you cast pointer to int it will properly add 4 bytes to it.

This is an explanation of what is going on.  I'm not sure what you are doing, but you most certainly should not be doing it like that.  This can get you in trouble with alignment etc.  The safe way to figure out offset of a struct element is:

```
  printf("%d\n", &(((foo_t *)NULL)->b));
```

Comment: `((int)&f + sizeof(int))` will wreak havoc on systems with `sizeof(int *) > sizeof(int)`. `(int*)&f + 1` or `(uintptr_t)&f + sizeof(int)` would work unless the compiler adds padding between the members.